# How to compile shader fx-file for use in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, pixel-shader

I have a Shader.fx-file and want to compile it into a Shader.ps-file that can be used as input to a ShaderEffect in WPF.

I'm using the compiler in Windows 10 SDK (fxc.exe) like this:

```
fxc /O0 /Fc /Zi /T  fx_5_0 /Fo Shader.ps Shader.fx
```

This works fine but when loading it in WPF I get an exception:

```
Shader bytecode must be an integral number of 4-byte words.
```

Any idea how to solve this? How do I get it to the correct size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was this:

```
/T fx_5_0
```

Should be:

```
/T ps_2_0
```